# Fetching data from S3 with akka-streams, akka-http

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to read a file from S3 and send it back to client from a akka-http based rest endpoint, like this:

```
def fetchFromS3(s3Uri: String):
      Future[Either[CustomError, Source[ByteString, NotUsed]]] = {
    val data = fetchDataAsStream(s3Uri)
      .map {
        case None => Left(CustomError(s"Data not found"))
        case Some((_, _, source)) => Right(source)
      }
    .recover { case error: Throwable =>
        Left(CustomError(s"Failed to fetch data due to ${error.getMessage}"))
      }
    
    data
  }
```

`fetchDataAsStream` uses AlpakkaS3Client to talk to S3 and returns `Future[Option[(ContentType, Long, Source[ByteString, NotUsed])]]`

So now I have `Future[Either[CustomError, Source[ByteString, NotUsed]]]`.

What is idiomatic way of processing this and send it back to client?

Comment: Akka HTTP is able to handle Akka `Source` as a response, see official documentation at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `fetchDataAsStream` has "ran" the stream already, when in fact the most idiomatic way for this would be that that function does not actually run the stream and turn it into a future. Instead, keep it as a source. Also keep the option as option already signifies that something was missing, where a Left with a string that says data was missing is kind of weird.

```scala
S3.download(bucket, key)
  .map {
    case Some((source, _)) => source
    case None => Source.empty
  }
  .flatMapConcat(_.fold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _).map(_.utf8String))
  .runWith(Sink.headOption)
```

If you do not have access to the source code for `fetchDataAsStream` or do no want to change the signature you can do:

```scala
fetchDataAsStream(s3Uri)
  .flatMap {
    case None => Future.successful(Left(CustomError(s"Data not found")))
    case Some((_, _, source)) => 
       source.runFold(ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _).map(_.utf8String).map(Right(_))
  }
```

Comment: OP says `fetchDataAsStream` returns a `Source`, thus it has not run.

Comment: Also transforming `Option` to `Either` is quite standard if absence of a data should be interpreted as an error. Though it's a matter of practices.

Comment: There are two streams when you call S3 download. The first one returns an optional source and metadata. The second source has the actual content.